# Running APT Commands in PHP

Tags: php, debian, apt

Does anyone know if running APT commands in PHP is possible, and if so, how? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean Debian's Advanced Packaging Tool, you can run apt commands using a variety of functions:

- `exec()`
- `passthru()`
- `shell_exec()`
- `system()`
- `proc_open()`

you can find the documentation for all of them here: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php

`exec()` is probably the one you want, since it lets you capture the return value and the output.

you could also use backticks: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php

Comment: Wow, PHP is amazing, and so is Cal.

Comment: hakre: for that you want to use proc_open(). the manual page explains how to send input to STDIN and then get the results out: http://uk.php.net/proc_open